# Back up and restore file permissions

Tags: files, permissions, backup, acl

Is there a way to back up and restore file ownership and permissions (the things that can be changed with `chown` and `chmod`)?

You can do this [in Windows using icacls](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/viewing-saving-and-restoring-ntfs-permissions/).

What about access control lists?

Comment: It would help if you stated which distro you are using, as different distros use different package managers.

Comment: @garethTheRed, does it also depend on the fs being used, or just the distro?

Comment: I doubt it would depend on the filesystem.

Comment: Till now, there's no perfect answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this with the commands from the [acl](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl/) package (which should be available on all mainstream distributions, but might not be part of the base installation). They back up and restore ACL when ACL are present, but they also work for basic permissions even on systems that don't support ACL.

To back up permissions in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively:

```
getfacl -R . >permissions.facl
```

To restore permissions:

```
setfacl --restore=permissions.facl
```

Comment: Hmm. I _really_ need to read up on ACLs.

Comment: In the generated file, are they relative to a directory too?

Comment: @leeand00 Yes, the generated file always uses relative file names.

Comment: @Gilles,based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364517/difference-between-chmod-vs-acl,if  `setfacl` files then cannot  `chmod` again,maybe will cause conflict?

Comment: @kittygirl I have no idea what you're asking. What does “setfacl files then cannot chmod again” mean? What does this have to do with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364517/difference-between-chmod-vs-acl,if ? What conflict?

Comment: @Gilles,consider ACL is not respected by other linux function like `cp`, I am afraid of using `setfacl`.

Comment: @Gilles,for the files only defined by `chmod` and `chown`,can `getfacl -R . >permissions.facl` and `setfacl --restore=permissions.facl`  get the origin permission of these files?

Comment: @kittygirl Yes.

Comment: @Gilles,does it work for filenames starting with whitespace, or containing non-printable characters?

Comment: @kittygirl Yes, including newlines.

Comment: @Gilles,there's big problem(maybe bug):run `setfacl` by root,cannot change a file like  `-rw-r--r--  1 root root`,

Comment: @kittygirl I don't understand your comment. When run by root, `setfacl` can change the permissions for any file.

Comment: @Gilles,actually I found a bug.When you run by root, you cannot change `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` to `-rw-r--r-- 1 usernotexistinyourmachine apache`.Normally,if username not exist,will be replaced by userid like `1001`.But if owner is `root`, cannot change to `1001`

Comment: @kittygirl Uh? Why not? Of course `notexistuser` has to exist. If you request to make a file owned by a user but you give an invalid user name, then the request is rejected, this is the correct behavior. Restoring won't invent a user ID for you, you have to restore the user account before restoring the files.

Comment: @Gilles,there's no any notice that request is rejected.And, ONLY `notexistuser`  keep the same,`group` and `permission` changed.Which means if you don't know exactly every user and group of a large `permissions.facl`,error may happen.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of anything "off the shelf" that would do this. Here's a starter script for you, though, that will handle basic permissions. It does not handle ACLs of any description - but your Question explicitly excludes those. (It will also fail on pathological filenames - those starting with whitespace, or containing non-printable characters.)

**Save the permissions**

```
find * -depth -exec stat --format '%a %u %g %n' {} + >/tmp/save-the-list
```

**Restore the permissions**

```
while read PERMS OWNER GROUP FILE
do
    chmod "$PERMS" "$FILE"
    chown "${OWNER}:${GROUP}" "$FILE"
done </tmp/save-the-list
```

Comment: do you mean ACL will also fail on pathological filenames?

Comment: @kittygirl I didn't include any processing of ACLs in the scriptlet because the OP had explicitly excluded them from the requirements. You can add what you like, bearing in mind that the code isn't particularly robust (see the comment describing pathological filenames).

Comment: I found a problem:cannot find `.htaccess`,`gitignore`...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# prepare files
home="/home/exchange"
cd $home
>acl
echo "#!/bin/bash">recovery_acl.sh
echo "cd $home">>recovery_acl.sh
f='./'
# create acl file sorted by dir_level
for i in `seq 0 15`;do
  find . -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i -type d -exec getfacl {} +|grep -E '*UTS|file:'>>acl
done
sed -i 's/default\:user/\-dm\ u/g' acl
sed -i 's/default\:group/\-dm\ g/g' acl
sed -i 's/user/\-m\ u/g' acl
sed -i 's/group/\-m\ g/g' acl
sed -i 's/\#\ file\:\ /\.\//g' acl
sed -i 's,\\,\\\\,g' acl

while IFS='' read -r line ; do
  # grep dir name
  if echo "$line" | grep -q "$f" ; then
    dir="$line"
    continue
  fi
  echo setfacl $line '"'$dir'"'>>recovery_acl.sh
  # grep non def acl (for files)
  if echo "$line" | grep -q '\-m' ; then
    echo setfacl $line '"'$dir'"'/*>>recovery_acl.sh
  fi
done < "acl"

sed -i "s/\\\134/\\\\\\\134/g" recovery_acl.sh
sed -i "s/\\\040/\\\\ /g" recovery_acl.sh
```

This bash script get acl only dirs (in my case files acls = dir(parent) acl )
After execution of script, will creating another "recovery_acl.sh".

While recovering Errors like "No such file or directory" means that dir is empty or dirname has two/more spaces together.